# VBA get length of string with white space characters like new line and carriage return

Tags: java, vba, excel

I'm trying to truncate Excel columns to certain length in VBA.

However `LEN` function doesn't seem to count `\n and \r` as individual characters.

Is there any other function that can give exact length of string ?

For example I'm trying to get length of following string in a cell. (`a\r\nb\r\nc\r\nd`)

```
a
b
c
d
```

Code to get length.

```
print len( replace(replace(sheet1.Cells(1,1).value, chr(10), "-" ), chr(13), "#"))
```

Output:

```
7
```

Actual length of the string is `10`.

**Edit**

I finally figured it out. It wasn't related to the white space characters but some other special Unicode characters.

VBA `LEN` function and Java `String.length()` methods do not give the size of the string but the count of characters. Since Oracle was using the byte length as the actual size of the column (`varchar(50) means 50 bytes`) it wasn't allowing the string to be inserted even after truncation.

I finally used following code to truncate the string at Java side, as I wasn't able to find any method to do so in VBA.

```
stringBytes = strCellValue.getBytes("UTF-8");
stringLength = stringBytes.length;

strCellValue = new String( stringBytes, 0, maxCellWidth, "UTF-8");
cell.setCellValue(strCellValue);
```

Thanks to David Zemens and P57 for the clues.

Comment: If you know the length you want to cut the string at, try `Application.Worksheetfunction.LEFT(string, # of chars you want to keep)`

Comment: It does the same thing, it doesn't consider the white space characters. I need to send the Excel to server where JDBC puts it into Oracle tables. There exact size of string is used.

Comment: Are you sure `Len` isn't counting those characters for you? This counts 2 for me `Len(ChrW(10) & ChrW(13))`

Comment: @P57 You're right, it counts the characters when they're directly supplied using `chr` function, however it doesn't count them from the cells.

Comment: Can you post more code then about how you're acquiring this string value, because that makes the string data more suspect than the Len function.

Comment: @P57 Please check the edits, I have added the details.

Comment: Are you certain that the cell contains both a carriage return **and** a line feed? When I supply some text using ALT+ENTER, and query the contents of the cell, there are only `vbLF` (line feed) characters, no `vbCR`.

Comment: I'm copying the text from the `notepad++`, it shows the text length when selected. `Notepad++` counts special characters as well. I have also tried to copy the string by printing it using Javascript. In Notepad, I can replace `\r\n` with `#%` and it gives me `a#%b#%c#%d`

Comment: Doesn't matter what's in Notepad++, it matters what's actually in your Excel cell. I suspect if you do a `Instr(sheet1.Cells(1,1).value, vbCRLF)` the result will be `0`, indicating that Excel is only interpreting the LineFeed, not the Carriage return *and* line feed.

Comment: Aww, copy and pasting into Excel is very important detail! Your carriage return (character code 13) is lost at that point, and is no longer in the string value contained in the cell.

Comment: @DavidZemens You're exactly right, it gives `0` for `vbCRLF` and `2 for chr(10)`, `0 for chr(13)` However when I read the excel back in Java it gives me the actual string with length 10.

Comment: Well I don't know about any of Java, or how it's reading the value(s), but as far as VBA is concerned the length of that cell is 7, not 10, and there are only 7 characters in the cell, not 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested copy/paste from Notepad++ and verified that it's not copying the carriage return.

If you check on your cell like:

`Instr(Sheet1.Cells(1,1).Value, vbCrLF)`

You'll see the result of `0` indicating that the `vbCrLF` (`Char(10) & Char(13)`) simply doesn't exist in the cell. The Clipboard must be altering the text stream somehow.

So the actual length of the string *in Excel* is only 7.

To fix this, convert the Line Feeds to a `vbCr & vbLf`:

```
Debug.Print Len(Replace(sheet1.Cells(1,1).value, vbLF, vbCR & vbLF))
```

**NOTE:** This probably isn't a one-size-fits-all approach, it assumes that *all* Line Feeds should be coerced to a Carriage Return + Line Feed. Your mileag may vary.

Advice is not to copy/paste from Notepad++, and consume text files directly as a TextStream object to your VBA...

Answer (score 1):

I'm still curious why you'd be seeing a character count of 10 for your example if reading the Excel value from Java.

This code gives some further insight into how an Excel range copies back to clipboard. It really looks like after pasting into the cell the carriage return is gone for good, but also that, after copying, the actual clipboard text includes quotations and has "\n\r" appended, but no trace of the original `\r` characters.

```
 Sub CellStringCheck()

    'Copy cell to clipboard
    Range("A1").Copy

    'Get clipboard contents directly
    Dim obj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set obj = New MSForms.DataObject
    obj.GetFromClipboard

    'Convert to string and set object to nothing
    Dim s As String
    s = obj.GetText
    Set obj = Nothing

    'Print Information
    Debug.Print "___________________"
    Debug.Print "String: "
    Debug.Print s
    Debug.Print "Len = " & Len(s)
    Debug.Print "Characters:"
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Debug.Print AscW(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next

End Sub
```

If I paste `A\n\rA` into range A1, this code produces the following:

```
    ___________________
String:
"A
A "

Len = 7
Characters:
34
65
10
65
34
13
10
```

If you paste this clipboard content back into NP++ you get quotations and all, but NP++ automatically converts the lone `\n` back into `\n\r`, apparently on its own because that's not part of the clipboard content.

I wondered if this had to do with the clipboard format being VbCFText, but if VBA handles the clipboard pasting, then there's no problem. No carriage returns are removed as shown by using this code:

```
    Sub CellStringCheck()

    'Set clipboard contents
    Dim obj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set obj = New MSForms.DataObject
    obj.SetText vbLf & vbCr
    obj.PutInClipboard

    'Copy cell to clipboard
    obj.GetFromClipboard
    Range("A1") = obj.GetText
    Range("A1").Copy

    'Get clipboard contents directly
    obj.GetFromClipboard

    'Convert to string and set object to nothing
    Dim s As String
    s = obj.GetText


    'Print Information
    Debug.Print "___________________"
    Debug.Print obj.GetFormat(1)
    Debug.Print "String: "
    Debug.Print s
    Debug.Print "Len = " & Len(s)
    Debug.Print "Characters:"
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Debug.Print AscW(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next

    Set obj = Nothing
End Sub
```

So, all this to say, I'm still not sure why you'd be finding carriage returns at all if reading the cell value directly from Java, but if you're going through the clipboard, then you may be picking up the appended carriage return. Apparently, Excel and NP++ do their own string handling when pasted to. Excel removes carriage returns, while NP++ converts `\n` to `\n\r`. If you go directly through the clipboard this doesn't happen, so I suspect it has to do with application level event handling. I haven't tested directly reading or writing to values from .Net or Java, but my guess is that directly accessing values would avoid this problem.  Another work around would be to use `Environment.NewLine` or force `\n\r` for any instance of `\n`.

Comment: I'm also looking into this, as when I copy back from Excel to Notepad I again get the carriage return characters. However I have decided to put the truncation logic on Java side just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the best answer; in fact, I'm quite sure of it, but one rather convoluted approach would be to prior to using `Len` function, do a replace on the carriage returns and new lines. Something like

```
for i = 1 to 10
    cells(i,1) = Replace(Cells(i,1), Char(10), "-") 'newline Chr(10)
    cells(i,1) = Replace(cells(i,1), Char(13), "-") 'carriage return Chr(13)
next i
```

Then you would have a dash where the newlines and carriage returns were and could apply `Len` to the cell in question to get the full length.

Comment: I thought of this already, unfortunately first line replaces both `\n and \r` in one go.

Comment: OK. I thought you wanted them both replaced?

Comment: I mean, `\r\n` are considered as single character. So if they appear consecutively, they would be counted as one.

Comment: I imagine you could replace the combination. `Replace(..., char(10) & char(13), "-")`

Comment: @11thdimension Once again, your actual string handling is suspect. `Replace(vbCrLf, Chr(10), "-")` very clearly provides me with two characters, keeping the carriage return and replacing the line feed with a dash... maybe how Excel's Range object handles the string or its variant form

Comment: `vbCrLf` should be two characters right ? `carriage return + line feed` ?

Comment: @11thdimension yes, but there is no `vbCrLf` in the cell. Only a line feed.

Answer (score 0):

can you give an example of your string.

```
Const vcr As String = "L" & vbCr & _
  "n" & vbCr & _
  "." & vbCr & _
  "."
Const vlf As String = "L" & vbLf & _
  "n" & vbLf & _
  "." & vbLf & _
  "."
Const vslashn As String = "l\nn\n.\n."

len(vcr) gives 7
len(vlf) gives 7

Dim vslashnConverted As String    
vslashnConverted = Replace(vslashn, "\n", crlf)

Len(vslashn) : 10
Len(vslashnConverted) : 4
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function to get your desired result

**Note: Considered \r and \n are two different characters**

```
Public Function getlength(d As Range) As Long
    getlength = WorksheetFunction.Sum((Len(d) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(d, "\r", ""))) / 2, (Len(d) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(d, "\n", ""))) / 2, Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(d, "\r", ""), "\n", "")))
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

**Note: Below function Considered \r\n as single character**

```
Public Function getlength(d As Range) As Long
    getlength = WorksheetFunction.Sum((Len(d) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(d, "\r\n", ""))) / 4, Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(d, "\r\n", "")))
End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: This gives me the same result length 7 for my example `a\r\nb\r\nc\r\nd`, actual number of character should be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Sub countStr()
   MsgBox (Len(Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Text))
End Sub
```

[count text from cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTgHx.jpg)